# Can't get audio message from Siri INSendMessageIntent

Tags: swift, sirikit

Stuck on attempt to send voice message with SiriKit.

Calling Siri command `Send audio message with AppName`, it's recording the message and then call `func handle(intent: INSendMessageIntent, completion: @escaping (INSendMessageIntentResponse) -> Void)`

But attached `Data` has length 0 and when I try to get file by direct URL I've got message `file:///var/tmp/SiriMessages/E262A828-A24E-452E-BF70-867F5653BEFE.caf: Unable to open «E262A828-A24E-452E-BF70-867F5653BEFE.caf», you have no permissions.`

I didn't found any permissions settings so asking for help.

```swift
func handle(intent: INSendMessageIntent, completion: @escaping (INSendMessageIntentResponse) -> Void) {
        let userActivity = NSUserActivity(activityType: NSStringFromClass(INSendMessageIntent.self))
        let MIMEType = "audio/x-caf"
        var resultCode: INSendMessageIntentResponseCode = .failure
        var response = INSendMessageIntentResponse(code: resultCode, userActivity: userActivity)
        
        if let audio = intent.attachments!.first?.audioMessageFile {

            let networkService = NetworkService() // Test service for uploading files

            let audioData =  audio.data
            let filePath = audio.fileURL!
            
            Task {
                var resultCode: INSendMessageIntentResponseCode = .success
                var response = INSendMessageIntentResponse(code: resultCode, userActivity: userActivity)
                
                await networkService.uploadAudioMessage(filePath: filePath, withMIMEType: MIMEType) // Here I've got permission error



                print("Size of file: \(audioData.count)") // Will output Size of file: 0
                print("Result success")
                
                completion(response)
                return
            }
        } else {
            print("no voice message attached")
            
            completion(response)
            return
        }
    }
```

Comment: Did you find any solution to this? I'm having trouble understanding if it's really possible to do that. I didn't succeed getting Siri to start recording audio, it keeps telling me my app can't handle audio messages